# How I can convert PCollection to a list in python dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a PCollection `P1` that contains a field of ID's . I want to take the complete ID's column from the PCollection as a list and pass this value to a BigQuery query for filtering one BigQuery table.

What would be the fastest and most optimized way for doing this?

I'm new to Dataflow and BigData. Can any one give some hints on this?

Thanks!

Comment: By using a BigQuery sink: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pipeline-io

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what I understood from your question you want to build the SQL statement given the IDs you have in `P1`. This is one example of how you can achieve this:

```
sql = """select ID from `table` WHERE ID IN ({})"""
with beam.Pipeline(options=StandardOptions()) as p:
         (p | 'Create' >> beam.Create(['1', '2', '3']) 
            | 'Combine' >> beam.combiners.ToList()
            | 'Build SQL' >> beam.Map(lambda x: sql.format(','.join(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '"', x))))
            | 'Save' >> beam.io.WriteToText('results.csv'))
```

Results:

```
select ID from `table` WHERE ID IN ("1","2","3")
```

The operation `beam.combiners.ToList()` transforms your whole PCollection data into a single list (which I used later on to inject in the SQL placeholder).

You can now use the SQL in the file `results.csv-00000-to-000001` to run this query against BQ.

I'm not sure if it's possible to run this query directly in the PCollection though (something like `(p | all transformations | beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(result sql))` ). I suppose reading from the end result file and then issuing the query against BQ would be the best approach here.

Comment: `beam.combiners.ToDict` is another CombineFn related to `beam.combiners.ToList`

Comment: More precisely, `beam.combiners.ToList()` creates a PCollection which contains a single entry - that entry being the list you want. You can then access that list from one of the worker machines, for example, using `beam.Map` as above. AFAICT there is no way to return that list directly back to the manager without storing it somewhere, e.g., as done in the WriteToText sink above.