# Getting List From PCollections

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, pipeline, dataflow

I want a list values from Pcollection.

```
PCollection<List<Integer>> lst =    bqT2.apply(ParDo.of(new 
UserId()));  // line 1
List myList = lst.getAll(); // line 2
```

but there is no "getAll()" function

I found something similar

```
    List<String> dummylist = Arrays.asList(dummy);
    DoFnTester<String,String> fnTester = DoFnTester.of(new AAA(mapview));
    fnTester.setSideInputInGlobalWindow(mapview, csvlist);
    //dummylines.apply(ParDo.of(fnTester));
    List<String> results = fnTester.processBatch(dummylist);
```

but I didn't found any way to use "DoFnTester" function for getting list items.

Is there any way to list from PCollection?

Just to elaborate more I have two PCollections.

```
PCollection   p1 = pipeline.apply("",
BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery("SELECT * from myTable where userid in " +  lst + ));
```

Note: lst is from line 1

Not sure if google dataflow doesn't support simple usecases.

Answer (score 2):

[`apache_beam.transforms.combiners.ToList`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.transforms.combiners.html#apache_beam.transforms.combiners.ToList) can work for you if the list fits on memory.

`beam.combiners.ToList()` is Python version.

Comment: `beam.combiners.ToList()` creates a PCollection with a single element, the list you want. However, it still doesn't allow you to access that list as an ordinary Python object.

Answer (score 0):

Data can't be accessed directly from a PCollection due to the distributed nature of dataflow pipelines.

Instead of converting to a list, do a "combine" transform to convert your PCollection of multiple integers to a PCollection containing a single list element needed in the SQL query, chained to another transform with your BigQuery read query using the previous PCollection (the list of integers).

Comment: Can you put more light on "combine" transform by modifying the above code?

Comment: Combine is a transform for combining collections of elements. When you apply a Combine transform, you must provide the function that contains the logic for combining the elements or values. Note that you will only be able to use those values once they are out of the pipeline.

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159236/9910124) provides an example of converting a PCollection to a list, and the SQL query is written to a file that then you can use to run the query.