# Reading of a file from Google Cloud Storage fails in a python + flask + gunicorn + nginx + Compute Engine app

Tags: python, file, blob, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Reading of a file downloaded from Google Cloud Storage fails in a python + flask + gunicorn + nginx + Compute Engine app. Link to the code: https://github.com/samuq/CE-test . The line number 64 of the file 'ETL_SHP_READ_SQL_WRITE' returns nothing, although the file is valid and has data in it:

```
prj_blob.download_to_file(self.prj_file)
logger.log_text(self.prj_file)
line 64 -->       euref_fin.ImportFromWkt(self.prj_file.read())).
```

Comment: What is the error? Include the stack trace.

Comment: I don't know how to view stack trace from python code in nginx+gunicorn server in Compute Engine, do you know how to do that @JohnHanley ?

Comment: Run your program without gunicorn. Enable debugging in your app. Repeat your steps to reproduce the error. In your code add a print statement to show what `self.shp_file` contains.

Comment: @JohnHanley, stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    test.test()
  File "test.py", line 12, in test
    with open('/tmp/shp-file', 'w+') as self.shp_file:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/shp-file'

Comment: How can I add permission to open a temp file from some tmp folder?

Comment: OK, I removed the shp-file from tmp-folder, and my test-script worked, but it still doesn't work with gunicorn + nginx.

Comment: Have you tried using the `tempfile` module?  ps: "doesn't work" isn't a problem description. pps: whenever there is a problem on a line doing multiple "things", e.g. `function1(function2())`, you might want to split them up so you can see what's going on between them. ppps: don't put the traceback in a comment, edit your question and include it there. pppps: getting access to the traceback in the environment you're running in should be priority #1 (no matter which environment that is), otherwise you're just trying random changes when you should be debugging...

Comment: @thebjorn I tried with tempfile, and the same error happens, the 'self.prj_file.read()' return nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file.seek(0) helped to solve the problem; somehow I assume that after blob.download_to_file(file_name) the file reader isn't in the start of the file.
Code:

```
    try:
        fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
        with os.fdopen(fd, 'w+') as prj_file:
            # do stuff with temp file
            prj_blob.download_to_file(prj_file)
            prj_file.seek(0)
            euref_fin.ImportFromWkt(prj_file.read())
            logger.log_text(str(euref_fin))
            logger.log_text('euref_fin printed!')
    finally:
        os.remove(path)
```